# Dynamically Inject JavaScript Modules in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I created a little demo here: https://codepen.io/min-width/pen/LYVVLwK

But just in case that gets lost in time, here is the JavaScript from that page (it's constructing a script tag with a type of "module" and injecting it into the page):

```
let value = `<script type="module">
  let element = document.createElement("p");
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The JavaScript executed."));
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(element);
</scr` + `ipt>`;
let compiled =
    document.createRange().createContextualFragment(value),
    body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(compiled);
```

When working, it should say "The JavaScript executed" in the body of the page. This works fine in most browsers (and I accept that it doesn't work in IE since IE doesn't support modules at all).

**My issue is that this does not work in Edge, even though Edge does have support for JavaScript modules:** https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

Edge just doesn't seem to like when modules are injected dynamically. Is there some client-side workaround for this? I currently have it working with a server-side check for "Edge" in the user agent (in which case I render the module immediately in the HTML rather than injecting it with JavaScript), but that doesn't feel like an optimal solution.

In case you are wondering, my use case is that I preload some JavaScript modules, then I inject them into the page when the user first interacts with the page (a page speed optimization that PageSpeed Insights seems to like).

**Edit:** Since somebody asked, here is the Edge version number info (from the settings):

[image: Screenshot of Edge version number]

It shows Edge 44 and EdgeHTML 18.

Comment: Which version of `Edge` are we speaking about here?

Comment: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: Where are you getting this version from? The last version of `Microsoft Edge` prior to the recently released `Chromium-based` Microsoft Edge was `Microsoft Edge 18`.

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot of the version number from the Edge settings.

Comment: Got it, so it's version `18`. I wonder if this has to do with `dynamic imports` not being supported in this version - https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import - but they are supported in the `Chromium-based` Edge. If possible, I would try to test it on the `Chromium-based` Edge, just as an experiment.

Comment: Though I am dynamically importing, I am not using the dynamic import syntax. Still, Edge may see them as similar, so I'll see if I can upgrade my version of Edge (good find, BTW). I would still like to know how to get this working without upgrading Edge for other users.

Comment: It works on the latest version of Edge (which makes sense, since it is essentially Chrome): Version 80.0.361.48 (Official build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify your code and it works with MS Edge 44 version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo page</title>

</head>
<body>


<script>
let se =document.createElement('script');
se.setAttribute('type', 'module');
se.innerHTML='var para = document.createElement("P"); para.appendChild (document.createTextNode("The JavaScript executed.")); document.querySelector("body").appendChild(para);';

let body = document.querySelector('body');
body.append(se);

</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Output in Edge browser:

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Maybe the issue is the combination of createContextualFragment and JavaScript modules? Or more generally, the combination of document fragments and JavaScript modules?

Comment: I think Edge getting confused with the code. You had started the script tag but there is no end. So I think this caused the issue.

Comment: Hmm, I did have a closing tag for the script (take another look at the fifth line of code from the question). I just had to split it into two strings so the browser wouldn't get confused and think that was the closing tag for the outer script tag, so I don't think that explains it. Note that I'm using back ticks for multi-line strings.

Comment: Ms edge is not able to understand it.